# How can I tell if a field is a non-custom formula field in the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, formula-field, streaming-api, pushtopic

We have an integration that allows users to specify criteria to listen for on arbitrary object types in Salesforce. The user specifies the object type they want to listen to updates on and then they specify which boolean fields on that object to check for true or false.

This criteria is then used to create or update a PushTopic so we can consume messages from the Streaming API.

The documentation on PushTopic queries states "Formula fields in WHERE clauses (formula fields are supported in SELECT clauses though.)" are not supported: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/unsupported_soql_statements.htm

In the field object returned by the sobject describe endpoint, there is a field "calculated" which "indicates whether the field is a custom formula field (true) or not (false)". When displaying field options to the end user we filter out calculated fields like this among other types.

The problem is that it appears that some built in fields (for example "IsHighPriority" on the "Task" object) come back as "calculated: false":

```
{
  aggregatable: false
  aiPredictionField: false
  autoNumber: false
  byteLength: 0
  calculated: false
  calculatedFormula: null
  cascadeDelete: false
  caseSensitive: false
  compoundFieldName: null
  controllerName: null
  createable: false
  custom: false
  defaultValue: false
  defaultValueFormula: null
  defaultedOnCreate: true
  dependentPicklist: false
  deprecatedAndHidden: false
  digits: 0
  displayLocationInDecimal: false
  encrypted: false
  externalId: false
  extraTypeInfo: null
  filterable: true
  filteredLookupInfo: null
  formulaTreatNullNumberAsZero: false
  groupable: true
  highScaleNumber: false
  htmlFormatted: false
  idLookup: false
  inlineHelpText: null
  label: "High Priority"
  length: 0
  mask: null
  maskType: null
  name: "IsHighPriority"
  nameField: false
  namePointing: false
  nillable: false
  permissionable: false
  picklistValues: []
  polymorphicForeignKey: false
  precision: 0
  queryByDistance: false
  referenceTargetField: null
  referenceTo: []
  relationshipName: null
  relationshipOrder: null
  restrictedDelete: false
  restrictedPicklist: false
  scale: 0
  searchPrefilterable: false
  soapType: "xsd:boolean"
  sortable: true
  type: "boolean"
  unique: false
  updateable: false
  writeRequiresMasterRead: false
}
```

I cannot see any indication on this field that would tell me it is a formula field or that I cannot use it in a WHERE clause in a PushTopic SOQL query. Setting a query on a PushTopic with this field in the WHERE clause succeeds, but then no messages are sent.

Ultimately the problem is that I need to be able to tell programmatically if a field is valid in the WHERE clause of a PushTopic query. What am I missing with these built in formula fields?

Comment: `defaultedOnCreate = false` and `updateable=false`  as a secondary check if `calculatedFormula = null` or `calculated=false`

Comment: I remember seeing everUpdateable field which indicates if a field is ever updateable (to distinguish from updateable due to access). Not able to find those reference.

Comment: `filterable: true` indicates a field can be used in SOQL `WHERE` condition, and it is true for `IsHighPriority` field

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think @cropredy’s solution is correct. While IsHighPriority is filterable and can be used in an SOQL query there are more limitations for PushTopic SOQL queries and it cannot be used there.